# Blackberry Twitter getting a pop up when getting request_token

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a phonegap based Blackberry app, in this I have twitter share feature.I have written code for getting request_token from twitter using oauth, I am getting a pop up saying that:Content at api.twitter.com requires authentication. Please enter username and password. This is not an expected functionality. Instead of this, I need to get request_token and open Twitter login page in a childbrowser but I don't know why I am getting this pop up? Please help me.Code I am using is as follows:

```
 oauth = OAuth(options);
    oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            function(data) {
                requestParams = data.text;
                window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?'+data.text, 
                        { showLocationBar : false });                    
            },
            function(data) { 
                alert('Error : No Authorization'); 
                console.log("AppLaudLog: 2 Error " + data); 
                $('#oauthStatus').html('<span style="color:red;">Error during authorization</span>');
            }
    );
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a different API. I think this is a BlackBerry WebWorks problem. See also: http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/1585866

Comment: @ Frank Groeneveld: Please check whether your device's date and time are set to the current. Then run the app.After doing this, I am not getting this pop up now.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't solve my problem.